# I have load balancer configured on Haproxy. Can load balancer redirect traffic from port 1 backend to port 2 backend if port 1 is busy this moment

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

In ha-proxy I separated my traffic to two frontend ports and created two backends. Port-1 traffic is directed both backend and port 2 traffic is directed two backend-2. I want to create a smart load balancer that detects if backend 2 is busy whit port 2 queries it will automatically send the traffic of port 1 to backend 1.

```
global
       log /dev/log    local0
       log /dev/log    local1 notice
       maxconn 3000
       user haproxy
       group haproxy
       daemon
       stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin
#       external-check
 
defaults
       log     global
       timeout connect 60000
       timeout client 6000000
       timeout server 6000000
       errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
       errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
       errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
       errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
       errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
       errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
       errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
 
#########################
frontend test_1
       mode tcp
       bind 0.0.0.0:74474   
         
       acl dp1 dst_port 34475
       use_backend test_two if dp1
       default_backend test_one
 
backend test_one
       balance leastconn
       mode tcp
#       option external-check
 
       option allbackups
 
       server server-1 192.128.22.1:25554 check
       server server-2 10.128.66.53:25554 check
     
backend test_two
       balance leastconn
       mode tcp
#       option external-check
 
       option allbackups
 
       
       server server-1 192.168.22.1:25554 check
```

Answer (score 0):

frontend binds to port 74474 and has an acl based on port 34475 which will never get hit because tthat front end isnt binding to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/516989)

Comment: i guess im confused as what 'busy' means and as what the purpose of the backend 1 vs backend 2 if 1) backend  1 will never be reached because the ACL will never be hit and 2) backend 1 and 2 both have 192.128.22.1:25554 as a node? lastly ... .what does 'busy' mean? like the node is down or unresponsive? In which case, you should define one of your nodes as a backup.